# Can I include a variable inside a mathematical expression raw string?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, mathematical-expressions

I'm trying to plot multiple histograms in the same subplot, and also add legends to it. The legends requires a string for each label. For each string, I'm using mathematical expressions, but I will also need to include a variable to it.

To be more specific, for each legend lable, I want it to look like r"$\mathcal{M}_{j}$" where j is a variable that I go through using a for loop.
I checked the [Matplotlib official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html), but there's no mentioning of this kind of usage. I also did a lot of google searching without results.

I also included a simplified code here to explain the problem more clearly:

## code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np


n = 3 # number of subplots
m = 4 # number of histograms in each subplot

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=n, ncols=1)

for ax in axs.reshape(-1):

    # put data to be plotted in this subplot in a list
    data_plot = []

    # list for legend label
    model_label_array = []

    for j in range(0, m):

        # generate random numbers to be plotted
        data_plot.append(np.randn(100))

        # generate label string for this group of data
        model_label_array.append("$\mathcal{M}_{str(j)}$")

    # plot
    ax.hist(data_plot,
            label=model_label_array)
```

the following graph is what I got right now:
[please click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3mTY.png)

I want the legends to look like $\mathcal{M}_{j}$ where j is the index of the model.

Comment: Are you possibly confused between raw strings and f-strings?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It seems like I want to add a f-string function into a raw string. Is there anyway to achieve it?

Comment: `f"$\mathcal{{M}}_{j}$"`

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you, the code that you gave worked. But I'm a little confused here, because the [documentation of matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) obviously says a raw string is needed. I wonder why a f-string is ok here?

Comment: `r"{"` is the same as `"{{"`.

Answer (score 0):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest has pointed out,

```
f"$\mathcal{{M}}_{j}$"
```

is the answer. Well, I feel kind of stupid. But in my defense I have always had the impression that a raw string is needed for a mathematical format string. Clearly this is not the case.

But there came more confusion: in the [documentation of matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) it does say a raw string is needed for math expression. Why don't we need it now?